# GAE Custom Domain Setup with a Godaddy hosted domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I got mostly everything setup. Since Google does not anymore allow naked domains so I've added my site on `www` subdomain. On my godaddy CNAME I've also added `www` and points it to `ghs.googlehosted.com`. Now I can view my site when I go to `www.mycustomdomain.com` however still when I go to `mycustomdomain.com` it is still showing me the godaddy parked domain page. I did some research and found that I need to point my `A record` to this IP `64.202.189.170`.

[image]

I've waited for days and it's showing me `This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.`

I'm a not sure what I'm doing wrong, or it just takes that long to reflect that change?

I'm also thinking about just **Forwarding and Masking** it to `www.mycustomdomain.com` so when I go to `mycustomdomain.com` it will redirect to `www.mycustomdomain.com`. I'm not sure if having `www` is good for SEO but I prefer simply `mycustomdomain.com`.

Comment: You do not need an A record. Have you setup your google apps account with the domain registered with it ?  You have not mentioned that anywhere here.

Comment: Ah yes I've already setup my account and on my domains it says `Redirect the naked domain http://....com to http://www....com`, this is good right? If I don't need the A record should I revert it back to the original IP set there?

Comment: hmm on the bottom of this status it also states there that `To enable this redirect, you must change the A record with your domain host.`

Comment: Sorry mis-interpreted what you where asking, you may well need an A record, but I don't know how godaddy can do the redirect, they may have a specific feature.  Normally your A record would point to a server that that does the redirect for you.  I use easydns, which does stealth forwarding of the naked domain. So I know nothing about godaddy features sorry.

Comment: No problem Tim. I've also another question hoping you can help me on this. What if I've successfully redirected my naked domain to my www subdomain, so I would have both the naked domain and subdomain to view my pages? Now is it possible to keep just one to access my site, I prefer just the naked domain, how can I go do another redirect from www subdomain to my naked domain. Thanks

Comment: No a redirect would mean all traffic will end up at www.  You could not do another redirect back, as you would end up with a loop.  Have a look at cloudflare, I think they may have a solution. They end up as front end proxy, then all traffic could be to the naked domain.